# format complex hash - simple_form gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, simple-form

I have a nested hash like this:

```
  LANGUAGE_DETAILS =  {
                       BG: {
                              Name: 'Български',
                              Flag: ''
                           },
                       EN: {
                              Name: 'English',
                              Flag: ''
                           },
                       RU: {
                              Name: 'Руский',
                              Flag: ''
                           },
                       UK: {
                              Name: 'Украински',
                              Flag: ''
                           }
                    }
```

and need to format it like the following hash:

```
 {
      BG: 'Български',
      EN: 'English',
      RU: 'Руский',
      UK: 'Украински'
  }
```

in order to use it as simple_form input parameter like this:

```
<%= f.input :language_code, collection: SecurityUser::LANGUAGE_DETAILS,
            label_method: :last,
            value_method: :first,
            as: :radio_buttons , label: 'Choose language' %>
```

Is there a way to transform the SecurityUser::LANGUAGE_DETAILS hash into new one in this context or I should create the hash on hand in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Hash[LANGUAGE_DETAILS.map{|k, h| [k, h[:Name]]}]
```